# Chrome on Android crashes when zooming/moving a VectorTile layer

Tags: android, google-chrome, openlayers-3, vector-tiles

We are creating a WebPpp for Tablets.

Because our WebApp needs to have **offline capabilities**, we are saving an entire VectorTile layer in a pouchDB (around 25k tiles).

This layer is used for orientation (much like google maps),
it includes streets, buildings, forests and so on.

The Tiles are generated with the GeoServer 2.11.1 Extension.

Now our problem is, chrome crashed ('Oh no' message) when we move the map around or zoom in/out. Firefox doesn't work better, doesn't crash but slow as hell.
For testing purposes I deactivated any styling (just basic) and just this layer is displayed.

Does anyone know why the browser crashes, or is there a way to find out?
Also are there alternatives?

Tablet that is used to test: Galaxy note pro, is this tablet just bad for graphical apps?
Other tablets did work fine.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be running low on memory. Configure your `ol.source.VectorTile` with a smaller `cacheSize`, e.g. 32 instead of the default (128).

```
new ol.source.VectorTile({
  cacheSize: 32,
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Still crashes but later then before.
What is this value? counts of Tiles or in MB?

Comment: It's the count of tiles. You can also set it to 0 if you're still experiencing problems. If you still get crashes with 0, there might be a memory leak. Would be interesting to analyze a codepen with a stripped down version of your app then.